# How do I see files that have diverged on two Git branches?

Tags: git

How I can see only the files that diverge between two branches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
git diff --name-only
```

to should only the names of the diverging files. Add to this command the commit SHA of the latest commit in your other branch

Answer (score 8):

```
$ git diff --name-only branch1 branch2
```

Answer (score -7):

Sounds like you need to find the Git equivelent to `bk changes -R <branch>` or `bk changes -L <branch>` which has bitkeeper tell you any change sets that are part of your local but not remote and vice versa.

Sorry I haven't really used Git extensively :(